# Mocrosoft Webhook Subscription for AzureA Users not working

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, webhooks, change-notification

I am trying to create webhook subscription for change notifications in Azure Active Directory, the subscription is successfully getting created and I am receiving events also for groups (create, update, delete). But when I created the subscription for Users, the subscription is successfully getting created but I am not getting any kind of events from that subscription. Before two weeks it was working fine for users but it has stopped working now.

Comment: Questions about your specific account should be asked at the vendor's site via their Customer Service link. We have no access to your account to see why something is or isn't working. This site is for specific questions related to programming (code) or use of a programmers tool. See [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/62576) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

If it worked fine before but it doesn't work any more without any changes to your application, it's very likely that there is a problem with the server.
In this case, please contact Azure Support as soon as possible to track your request.